# Which CLI application should I use to convert Word template (*.dot file) to the plain text?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, microsoft-word

I have several Microsoft Word template files. They have *`*.dot`* extension:

> ```
> $ file file.dot
> file.dot: Composite Document File V2 Document, Little Endian, Os: Windows, 
> Version 6.1, Code page: 1252, Author: user, Template: file.dot, Last Saved By: 
> user, Revision Number: 2, Name of Creating Application: Microsoft Office Word, 
> Total Editing Time: 01:00, Last Printed: Tue Nov 21 14:41:00 1995, Create
> Time/Date: Fri Dec 20 11:46:00 2019, Last Saved Time/Date: Fri Dec 20 11:46:00 
> 2019, Number of Pages: 3, Number of Words: 300, Number of Characters: 1713,
> Security: 0
> ```

I need to convert them to plain text using some CLI application.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is also `antiword` (use [deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=antiword)), which extracts plain text from old (pre-XML) Word documents in a very efficient, but not always entirely correct way.

Answer (score 16):

You can use LibreOffice in the terminal.

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt:Text YOUR-DOCUMENT-HERE.DOT
```

Check out the sources
[Source1](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1671/is-there-a-command-line-tool-to-convert-documents-to-plain-text-files/)
[Source2](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/)

Comment: Looks as the most straightforward solution. Still can't find alternative for it.

Comment: There is no other applications that can read `dot` files on Ubuntu, except Libreoffice and OpenOffice. So I don't think there is an alternative. Maybe the one could be to use MS Office in wine.

Comment: @Pilot6 [About that](https://askubuntu.com/a/1197589/743264)...

Comment: @Pilot6: [I'm sure there is...](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=abiword)